# Creating and calling dynamic date link in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code which generates a dynamic date string, I want to put in into a web link so I can call the link to generate a new image each day.

I have written this code:

```
<script>
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();

document.getElementById("link").href = "http://earth.nullschool.net/#" + year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "/1200Z/wind/isobaric/500hPa/";
</script>

<a href="http://earth.nullschool.net/#2012/01/24/1200Z/wind/isobaric/500hPa/" id="link">500 mb Earth Wind Map</a>
```

However when I click this link it goes to the old date (2012), not the current date that the javascript creates. How do I create the link with today's date inside it?

Comment: You should place the script *below* the element that it wants to modify. If the order is as you have depicted it, then you should get an error message in the console.

Comment: You are getting an error in your console about `href` not being a property of null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the anchor tag before the script.

```
<a href="http://earth.nullschool.net/#2012/01/24/1200Z/wind/isobaric/500hPa/" id="link">500 mb Earth Wind Map</a>

<script>
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();

document.getElementById("link").href = "http://earth.nullschool.net/#" + year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "/1200Z/wind/isobaric/500hPa/";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works but it should so for your last line you can do this instead

```
<a href="http://earth.nullschool.net/#{}/{}/{}/1200Z/wind/isobaric/500hPa/".format(year,month,day) id="link">500 mb Earth
```

Since you are using a format method u are substituting your variable into the brackets.